# Bootstrap 4 flex grid system only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

So in bootstrap3 we had the 'Customize and download' option, which we could download only whatever we needed. Now that bootstrap 4 supports flexbox, I only wanna download the flex grid system of bootstrap 4 and I cant see that option anymore. is there any way to do this ?

Comment: v4 is still in _alpha_ stage - so I'd expect they focus on core development/bugfixing for now, and will add customizing features later on.

Comment: **Update** as of 4.1 you can download/use **grid only** as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083265/bootstrap-4-1-to-get-grid-system-only

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### UPDATE (JULY 2019)

With the release of [v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#css-files) you can simply use either `bootstrap-grid.css` or `bootstrap-grid.min.css` , it only includes [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) and [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

[image: SS]

---

#### Old Answer:

At this Alpha stage, you can toggle between true/false for using flexbox (if using a CSS preprocessor) as per [bootstrap V4 Alpha docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/)

> Flexbox support has finally come to Bootstrap. Opt-in to the new CSS
>   layout styles with the flick of a variable or the swap of a
>   stylesheet.

[How it works:](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/#how-it-works)

> If you’re familiar with modifying variables in Sass—or any other CSS
>   preprocessor—you’ll be right at home to move into flexbox mode.
>
> 1. Open the `_variables.scss` file and find the `$enable-flex` variable.
> 2. Change it from `false` to `true`.
> 3. Recompile, and done!
>
> Alternatively, if you don’t need the source Sass files, you may swap
>   the default Bootstrap compiled CSS with the compiled flexbox
>   variation. [Head to the download page](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download) for more information.

Comment: If you are using SASS/SCSS you need these `/mixins/`: `variables, clearfix, breakpoints, grid-framework, grid` and `custom` has to be erased in the main `grid-bootstrap.scss` file.

Answer (score 9):

At the time of answering this question, if you download the compiled .zip found [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/), it comes with a css folder that has three stylesheets,

- `bootstrap-grid.css`
- `bootstrap-normalize.css`
- `bootstrap.css`

The `bootstrap-grid` file has only the grid CSS and nothing else, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2019, Bootstrap 4.3+**

You can get the **grid only** using **bootstrap-grid.css** included in the Bootstrap 4 download. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files

This includes the grid, flexbox and display utilities, but not all the utilities like the borders, spacing, etc.. If you want a further 'Customize and download' option you must rebuild Bootstrap using SASS, or use a 3rd party tool like [themestr.app](https://themestr.app)

---

**Original Answer, Bootstrap 4 alpha (flexbox optional)**

There may be customizable downloads in the future, but the only way currently is to enable the `$enable-flex` variable. Here's an example using SASS.

`$enable-flex:true;`

http://codeply.com/go/JbGGN4Ok3A

As of Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, flexbox is now the default:
http://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.0.alpha.6

Answer (score 3):

## For Bootstrap 5+

After installing to `node_modules` using your package manager (e.g. `yarn add bootstrap@5`):

### SASS Compilation

This is preferred typically, as you can adjust variable values in compilation (see [their docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#variable-defaults) for more details)

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap components as you like
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';
```

### CSS Only

```css
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css';

// or for a minified version 

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to use flex-grid. I recommend

https://www.flexible-grid.com

https://github.com/kenangundogan/flexible-grid

```
flexible-grid/
    ├── scss
        ├── flexible-grid.scss
        ├── _variables.scss
        ├── _definitions.scss
        ├── _wrapper.scss
        ├── _array-list.scss
        ├── _attribute.scss
        ├── _grid.scss
        └── _normalize.scss
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 grid + Bootstrap 4 reboot -= 40kb
Your option is about twice as larger
(took not-minified versions)