# bootstrap 4.1 - to get grid system only

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hails guys!
Is there a way to customize **Bootstrap 4.1** to build a custom version with only two things: **Grid system and Responsive utilities**.
Here is the link to do that for 3.3 but for some reason the final compilation doesn't work:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

I could do that manually from the original file but, maybe there is a way to get that from Bootstrap instead of stripping their CSS off.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use `bootstrap-grid.css` included in the Bootstrap 4 download.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files

This includes the **grid, flexbox** and **display utilities**, but not *all* the utilities like the borders, spacing, etc..

Comment: woah, thanks man. slightly not intuitive (compared to the previous tool) but  - exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if this changed since your answer, it says now you get: layout (Only grid system) and Utilities (Only flex utilities)