# Import only grid system from bootstrap to react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I only need the grid system from bootstrap in my react app, because the default styling from bootstrap crashes my style. How can I only use the grid system ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 flex grid system only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684023/bootstrap-4-flex-grid-system-only)

Comment: What do you mean by only the grid system? Are you using React-Bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to reference the grid only CSS from the React public/index.html

```
<link 
rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-4-react-hello-world-7b8xw

Answer (score 4):

Just `npm install` or `yarn add` the `boostrap` package....then in your global `css` just import `boostrap-grid.css` (or the `min`) from the `dist` folder in your `node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

After installing Bootstrap with NPM using `npm i bootstrap` or with YARN using `yarn add bootstrap`. Then, in your [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) App, in `index.js`, import only the grid system from Bootstrap like so:

```js
// in src/index.js 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';
```

Then in your App.js, then use like so:

```js
// in src/App.js

import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";



export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col
            xs={{ span: 12, order: 1 }}
            md={{ span: 3, order: 1 }}
            lg={{ span: 3, order: 1 }}
          >
          </Col>


          <Col
            xs={{ span: 12, order: 2 }}
            md={{ span: 9, order: 2 }}
            lg={{ span: 6, order: 2 }}
          >
            {children}
          </Col>

          <Col
            xs={{ span: 12, order: 3 }}
            md={{ span: 12, order: 3 }}
            lg={{ span: 3, order: 3 }}
            className="d-none d-lg-block"
          >
            To be hidden
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```